# How do I get this `f.button` to display & work the way I want it to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

In my `simple_form` form, I have a button tag that has an icon.

I am trying to get my form to work like this:

```
<button class="input-submit">
    <i class="icon-circle-right"></i>
</button>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Icon-Arrow-Submit]

However, this is my `simple_form button` block:

```
<%= f.button :submit, value: "card-#{node_counter}", id: "submit-card-#{node_counter}", class: "input-submit", data: { disable_with: "Submitting Comment..." } do %>
     <i class="icon-circle-right"></i>
<% end %>
```

The issue I am running into is that I have to use the `value: "card-#node_counter"` attribute in my button for it to work properly in my AJAX form, but once I specify that `value` attribute, my HTML renders like this:

```
<input class="btn input-submit" data-disable-with="Submitting Comment..." id="submit-card-0" name="commit" type="submit" value="card-0">
```

And then looks like this:

[image: See-Value-As-Submit-Button]

When I use the default `f.button` with my `simple_form_for` though, the form works the way I want - i.e. via AJAX and the respective elements on the page are updated.

If I try to use `content_tag` instead, then the form doesn't submit in an AJAX way for w/e reason, but it does look the way I want and the HTML I want looks closer to my ideal. i.e. if I do this:

```
    <%= content_tag(:button, '', name: :submit, value: "card-#{node_counter}", id: "submit-card-#{node_counter}", class: "input-submit", data: { disable_with: "Submitting Comment..." } ) do %>
        <i class="icon-circle-right"></i>
    <% end %>
```

It renders this:

```
<button class="input-submit" data-disable-with="Submitting Comment..." id="submit-card-0" name="submit" value="card-0">
            <i class="icon-circle-right"></i>
</button>
```

And looks like this:

[image: content-tag-button-display]

So, in summary...I can't quite get both the look and the behavior I want. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. So the problem was that the JS I was using to update the interface after the form got submitted was expecting a `params[:card_id]` to be present and with my `content_tag` as I specified above, I had changed the `name` attribute from `card_id` to `:submit`....thinking that is what would make my form submit. But that's not what makes it submit.

So I just changed it to:

```
    <%= content_tag(:button, '', name: "card_id", value: "card-#{node_counter}", id: "submit-card-#{node_counter}", class: "input-submit", data: { disable_with: "Submitting Comment..." } ) do %>
        <i class="icon-circle-right"></i>
    <% end %>
```

And now this works.

The bit from my controller, in case you are wondering is:

```
  def create
    @node = Node.find(params[:node_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.node = @node
    @card_id = params[:card_id]
```

Now all is fixed in the world. It both looks and functions like I expect it to.